# Terrain Generation - Only draws first sprite and last row on the X axis

Tags: c++, procedural-generation, sfml

So, I have a problem where I'm trying to loop trough columns of sprites, that later will be drawn to fill a specific area.

But it only renders the first sprite and the last row of sprites on the X axis.

Like this :

[image: Picture]

As you see it doesn't fill the entire "screen".

---

This is how I try to loop trough all the sprites and draw them :

```
void EntityManager::GenerateMap(float xSize, float ySize, int texture)
{
    // Generates a series of rooms connected so eachother with random positions and size.
    Random randomGen;

    roomTextures.push_back(sf::Texture());

    if (!roomTextures[texture].loadFromFile("Resource/Images/Test.png"))
        std::cout << "Failed to load texture from file." << std::endl;
    else
    {

        for (int y = 0; y < ySize; y++)
        {
            std::cout << "y : " << y << std::endl;
            for (int x = 0; x < xSize; x++)
            {
                std::cout << "x : " << x << std::endl;
                roomSprites.push_back(new sf::Sprite());
                roomSprites[x]->setPosition(sf::Vector2f(x * 32, y * 32));
            }
        }

        std::cout << roomSprites.size() << std::endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < roomSprites.size(); i++)
        {
            roomSprites[i]->setTexture(roomTextures[texture]);
            //std::cout << "x : " << roomSprites[i]->getPosition().x << " y : " << roomSprites[i]->getPosition().y << std::endl;
        }
    }

}
```

Where `xSize = 10`, and `xSize = 10` and `texture = 0`.

And here's the "definitions" of the array list things :

```
std::vector<sf::Sprite*> roomSprites;
std::vector<sf::Texture> roomTextures;
```

---

Update :

So, I tried looping trough the sprite positions which resulted in this :

[image: Picture]

There were more positions below those, all of them being `x: 0 y: 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
roomSprites[x]->setPosition(sf::Vector2f(x * 32, y * 32));
```

What do you think will happen in the second row? `x` will start at 0 again and you'll set the position of the first 10 sprites. In the third row, `x` will start at 0 again and you'll set the position of the first 10 sprites. See where this will end? You either have to calculate the correct offset into your 1d-array from your 2d-coordinate:

```
roomSprites[y * xSize + x]->setPosition(sf::Vector2f(x * 32, y * 32));
```

or you'd set the position **before** you `push_back` the sprite:

```
sf::Sprite* sprite = new sf::Sprite();
sprite->setPosition(sf::Vector2f(x * 32, y * 32));
sprite->setTexture(roomTextures[texture]); //No need for another iteration over the vector to set the texture...
roomSprites.push_back(sprite);
```

Comment: Ohhh, that makes sense. Thank you! Not sure why I didn't think of this... :P